# How can I understand what this JavaScript code means?

Tags: javascript

What does this JavaScript code mean?

```
img.file = file;

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(aImg) { 
    return function(e) { 
        aImg.src = e.target.result; 
    }; 
})(img);
```

Specifically this

```
reader.onload = (function(){...})()
```

Comment: (function(){...})() it's a self calling function. It does call itself and do whatever the tasks are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE  would be helpful in your case.

It creates a function and immediately calls it. You can find some use cases in  the link above